# Why can't I loop over self in a Range extension?

Tags: swift

I have this extension:

```
extension Range {
    func foo() { // called with (0..<5).foo()

        let bar = 0..<5

        print(bar) // 0..<5
        print(self) // 0..<5

        print(type(of: bar)) // Range<Int>
        print(type(of: self)) // Range<Int>

        for i in bar { // :)

        }

        for j in self { // :(

        }
    }
}
```

For some reason, the first loop is fine, but the second isn't. I get a compile time error saying

```
Type 'Bound' does not conform to protocol 'Strideable'
```

Something that's also interesting to note here is that assigning `bar` with `self` effects the error to pop up in the first loop.

Comment: `extension Range where Bound == Int { ... }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make it explicit to the compiler that the `Bound` is `Strideable` :

```
extension Range where Element: Strideable {
    ...
}
```

Defining a `Range` only requires the `Bound` to only be `Comparable`. See the actual implementation [here](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4e86c8ff52aebdd4b19950f5e2b4bbb6d2822b62/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift#L129). `Comparable` is the minimum requirement to define a `Range`.

There are two types of ranges :

- `CoutableRange`s: These are ranges over types (`Bound`) that conform to `Strideable` and use integer steps between elements. These ranges are treated like a `Sequence`, and thus can be used in `for` loop.
- *Normal* ranges: These include `Range` and `ClosedRange` with `Comparable` elements only, and thus can't be iterated over.

This is explicitly given in [this](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/4e86c8ff52aebdd4b19950f5e2b4bbb6d2822b62/stdlib/public/core/Range.swift#L112) comment.

Comment: Thanks, that works, but it doesn't explain fully what causes this. Why does this make a difference?

Comment: @KevinWessels - `Range` only indicates the upper and lower bounds. It’s `Strideable` that has a method to advance to the next value. So you can only iterate through a range if the range’s element is `Strideable`.

Answer (score 4):

In the `bar` example, the compiler knows that `bar` is `0..<5`. But in the `self` example, the compiler does not know what `self` will be.

So now consider this code:

```
for i in 0.0..<1.0 {}
```

It doesn't compile. Why not? Because the whole notion of cycling thru a range of Double with `for...in` doesn't make sense.

Well, in your code, the compiler doesn't know that your Range (`self`) won't be a range of Double. You have to *guarantee* that it won't be. So you have to specify that your extension is meant to work only when the range is something for which `for...in` makes sense.

You could do that by specifying that this will be a range of Int or SignedInteger, but the most general way to specify it is by saying that your range will be a range of Strideable.